# Plant identification: white or black mulberry?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

West Massachusetts. Most of the info I can find online describes the differences between white and red mulberries. Based on those descriptions, the prominent veins on the back of the leaves would suggest white mulberries. However, the leaf surface feels rough and not smooth, which would suggest not white mulberries. So are these black mulberries?

Also, are all types of mulberry trees considered a nuisance and disliked?

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]
[image: Pic 3]

Comment: Mulberries are awesome, and very useful. You should be able to tell better by the bud color. They might be an interspecies hybrid or any of loads of other species of mulberry besides white and black.